# String replace troubles

Tags: string, batch-file

I am trying to read a file and remove the forward slash character (/) from each line. Here's what I have:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%BRANCH_OUT%) do SET THIS_BRANCH=%%A && ECHO %THIS_BRANCH:/=%
```

It works great, but the echo only displays the last line in the file for each line. So, a file containing:

Dir1/

Dir2/

Dir3/

Would be read and output as

Dir3

Dir3

Dir3

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Ok, I answered my own question. I used this `for /F "tokens=1 delims=/" %%A in (%BRANCH_OUT%) do ECHO %%A` but I would still like to see if anyone could provide an answer as to why the last line of the file kept coming up. Thanks.

Comment: If you have solved this problem, you can post the solution as an answer (even though it is an answer to your own question) and then even accept it after like 2 days.

Comment: Why only the last line? Because your environment was dirty. Any value set into the environment like `this_branch` remains set until explicitly removed with `set "this_branch="` or it's set to some other value. Any change to the environment made after a `setlocal` command is backed out by a matching `endlocal` or reaching end-of-file in the same context; hence the normal first 2 lines of a batch are `@echo off` and `setlocal` to clear the changes from the environment when the batch is finished. See endless SO articles on `delayedexpansion` for why `this_branch` is displayed unchanged in a `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign and then use a variable in a `for loop`, you must enable and used delayed expansion.  For instance, given the following:

```
c:\>@for %i in (a b c d) do @set _x=%i && @echo %_x%
d
d
d
d
```

This echos the **d** character 4 times, like you observed.  If you have delayed expansion enabled and you change it like this, it echos each of the 4 letters instead of **d** 4 times.

```
c:\>@for %i in (a b c d) do @set _x=%i && @echo !_x!
a
b
c
d
```

So, in your batch file, you need to add `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the beginning of the batch file, and `endlocal` at the end.  This makes sure that you can use the `!_x!` notation to get the delayed expansion.

Comment: One other point - the constant display of `d` is due to the residual value of _x from a prior run. The very first run when _x is initially undefined would yield `ECHO is on`. The situation is similar with the OP's constant display of `Dir3`.